# Amplify UI is not working proper in React js

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I am using AWS amplify for user authentication. UI is not what expected but no problem with functionality.

[image]

Amplify dependencies

```
"dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.1.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "aws-amplify": "^4.3.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  }
```

My app.js

```
import logo from "./logo.svg";
import "./App.css";
import Amplify from "aws-amplify";
import awsconfig from "./aws-exports";
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
Amplify.configure(awsconfig);

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        {/* <AmplifySignOut /> */}
        <h2>Amplify App</h2>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add css import, this line before `Amplify.configure`.

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui/dist/style.css';
```

This is breaking change of Amplify 3.x to 4.x.

Detail is written in this site.
https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/5445

Comment: Note: this is no longer true for the latest version of ui-react. The import should look like this:

`import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';`

See: https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 3):

Latest version of Amplify supports below stylesheet

```
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css';
```

For more details visit [Official AMPLIFY documents](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/getting-started/installation)

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this exact same issue. I went through the `@aws-amplify` files and it turns out that `ui-react-v1` needed to be imported instead of the `ui-react`. Try importing the following line to get your styling to show correctly like the module example.

`import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-v1';`

I hope this helps you out and anyone else getting this issue!

Comment: This is only true if you are want to use the legacy version of the Authenticator. To use the latest, version, follow the comment by @saud00 above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71210767/3574639

Answer (score 0):

You should import the styles of `@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css`

Here is where you put the `import` in the `index.js` file.

```
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';
import config from './aws-exports';
import '@aws-amplify/ui-react/styles.css'; // ** this is missed importing **
Amplify.configure(config);
```