# Export 'AmplifySignOut' was not found in '@aws-amplify/ui-react'

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, continuous-integration, aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli

I am **fresh new** to AWS Amplify, so I am following a tutorial on [AWS Build a Full-Stack React Application](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-intro), it's on Virtual Box with the latest Ubuntu image.

During step 3, I got an error when running the app locally

[image]

I did some research and tried downgrading the ui-react version from `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.5.0"` by installing with `sudo npm install aws-amplify @aws-amplify/ui-react@v1`, after downgrading it to `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^1.2.26"`, it works perfectly when running locally, but when I push it into Git for the automation, the Amplify CI/CD build throws this Error.

So I changed it back to `"@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^2.5.0"` and push, it still throws the same Error.

```
2022-02-20T04:20:57.602Z [INFO]: Successfully cleaned up Git credentials
2022-02-20T04:20:57.602Z [INFO]: # Checking for Git submodules at: /codebuild/output/src665494917/src/amplifyapp/.gitmodules
2022-02-20T04:20:57.626Z [INFO]: # Retrieving environment cache...
2022-02-20T04:20:57.683Z [INFO]: # Retrieved environment cache
2022-02-20T04:20:57.683Z [INFO]: ---- Setting Up SSM Secrets ----
2022-02-20T04:20:57.683Z [INFO]: SSM params {"Path":"/amplify/d47wligptyjbe/staging/","WithDecryption":true}
2022-02-20T04:20:57.721Z [WARNING]: !Failed to set up process.env.secrets
2022-02-20T04:20:57.721Z [INFO]: No live updates for this build run
2022-02-20T04:20:57.730Z [INFO]: # Retrieving cache...
2022-02-20T04:20:59.472Z [INFO]: # Extracting cache...
2022-02-20T04:21:02.981Z [INFO]: # Extraction completed
2022-02-20T04:21:25.314Z [INFO]: ## Starting Backend Build
                                 # Starting phase: build
2022-02-20T04:21:28.545Z [INFO]: [31mInvalid feature flag configuration[39m
2022-02-20T04:21:28.548Z [INFO]: [31mThese feature flags are defined in the "amplify/cli.json" configuration file and are unknown to the currently running Amplify CLI:[39m
                                 [31m  - project[39m
                                 [31m  - graphqltransformer.transformerversion[39m
                                 [31m  - graphqltransformer.suppressschemamigrationprompt[39m
                                 [31m  - graphqltransformer.securityenhancementnotification[39m
                                 [31m  - graphqltransformer.showfieldauthnotification[39m
                                 [31m  - auth.useenabledmfas[39m
                                 [31mThis issue likely happens when the project has been pushed with a newer version of Amplify CLI, try updating to a newer version.[39m
                                 [31mEnsure that the CI/CD pipeline is not using an older or pinned down version of Amplify CLI.[39m
                                 [31mLearn more about feature flags: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/reference/feature-flags[39m
2022-02-20T04:21:28.555Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2022-02-20T04:21:28.556Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
```

Can anyone give me some advice on how to fix it? I don't know why the official AWS Amplify tutorial would go like this, I have no idea about React and Amplify so I am very strugling.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting this exact same issue. Also this was related to the styling not populating like in this other question as well here, [Amplify UI is not working proper in React js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70319172/amplify-ui-is-not-working-proper-in-react-js/71432096#71432096)
.

I went through the `@aws-amplify` files and it turns out that `ui-react-v1` needed to be imported instead of the `ui-react`. Try importing the following line to get your styling to show correctly like the module example.

`import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-v1';`

I hope this helps you out and anyone else getting this issue!

Comment: This is only true if you are want to use the legacy version of the Authenticator, which we wouldn't recommend. To use the latest version, follow the instructions here:
https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/getting-started/installation

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue whilst following the [AWS Full Stack Tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-five/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-four), not building locally or when pushed to AWS via Amplify.

Changing the version of ui-react in the dependencies block of package.json does not solve this problem for me.

As per the Amplify docs, you need to add "-v1" after the framework name on the import line as per Ian's comment (https://stackoverflow.com/users/6632263/ian-brown) to get a successful build.

```
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react-v1';
```

My upstream build worked as well.